# How to bind multi actions to the one of props object mount point

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux

When i use react-redux, I want to write in the follow style.

```
this.props.http.list()
this.props.http.detail()
this.props.http.create()
```

How should i bind multi actions to props?

thank you.

Answer (score 0):

As described [here](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux/blob/master/docs/api.md#connectmapstatetoprops-mapdispatchtoprops-mergeprops-options):

```
import * as todoActionCreators from './todoActionCreators'
import * as counterActionCreators from './counterActionCreators'
import { bindActionCreators } from 'redux'

function mapStateToProps(state) {
  return { todos: state.todos }
}

function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch) {
  return bindActionCreators(Object.assign({}, todoActionCreators, counterActionCreators), dispatch)
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodoApp)
```

Use `mapDispatchToProps` to bind component function with action creator from redux

Comment: tks, but i want to get a collection action in props, for example:

Comment: tks, but i want to get a collection action in props, for example: this.props.http.list(), this.props.http.create(). I have edit the question description.

Comment: It's all there. If Your action creator will return object with `list`, `create` and `detail` functions, You'll be able to use then. `mapDispatchToProps` only let's You call these actions without calling dispatch